# How to implement a trait for a parameterized trait

Tags: rust, traits

I have a design issue, when using something like :

```rust
trait MyTrait<K: OtherTrait> { ... }

impl<K: OtherTrait, M: MyTrait<K>> AnyTrait for M { ... }
```

I cannot implement trait for this trait due to E207 error ("the type parameter `K` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates").

Finding no way to get rid of this error, I apply [this not-so-good-looking workaround](http://is.gd/PyowCE) (verbose and struct with no intrinsic value):

```rust
use std::fmt;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub trait MyTrait<K: fmt::Display> {
    fn get_some_k(&self) -> Option<K>;
}

/* // This is my target impl but results in E207 due to K not constrained
impl<K: fmt::Display, S: MyTrait<K>> fmt::Display for S {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.get_some_k().unwrap())
    }
} */
pub struct Ugly<'a, K: fmt::Display, S: 'a + MyTrait<K>>(&'a S, PhantomData<K>);
impl<'a, K: fmt::Display, S: MyTrait<K>> fmt::Display for Ugly<'a, K, S> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.0.get_some_k().unwrap())
    }
}

fn main() { }
```

I think there should be some nicer way to implement a trait for this kind of parameterized trait.

I did not find good example in std (for instance no `Display` implementation in traits with associated type like `Iterator`)?

Comment: Just thought I'd mention I'm running into the exact same issue, however I don't have the luxury of wrapping the blanket impl in an `Ugly`, as `MyTrait` is a public trait exposed to users, and requiring them to use an `Ugly` thoroughly ruins the API by adding unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Providing Blanket Trait Implementations for a Custom Trait](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430659/providing-blanket-trait-implementations-for-a-custom-trait)

Answer (score 5):

[Here’s an implementation using associated types](http://is.gd/h3NJwR) (which means that you can only implement `MyTrait` for one `K` per type):

```rust
use std::fmt;

pub trait MyTrait {
    type K: fmt::Display;
    fn get_some_k(&self) -> Option<Self::K>;
}

impl<S: MyTrait> fmt::Display for S {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.get_some_k().unwrap())
    }
}

fn main() { }
```

However, when clarified like this it becomes clear that this approach won’t work either, because you’re implementing `Display` for all types that implement `MyTrait`—types that could have their own `Display` implementation. This is forbidden, and so you get E0210:

> error: type parameter `S` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g. `MyStruct<T>`); only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter [E0210]

Wrapping it in something—like your `Ugly` did—is the only way to allow such an implementation. Or implement a trait in your own crate rather than one in someone else’s (like `Display` is).

Comment: thanks, I thought about associated type, but I am in the case where I need multiple implementations per type, otherwise it would have done the job (my use case is not `Display`).