# Providing Blanket Trait Implementations for a Custom Trait

Tags: rust

I am implementing a quick geometry crate for practice, and I want to implement two structs, `Vector` and `Normal` (this is because standard vectors and normal vectors map through certain transformations differently). I've implemented the following trait:

```
trait Components {
  fn new(x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) -> Self;
  fn x(&self) -> f32;
  fn y(&self) -> f32;
  fn z(&self) -> f32;
}
```

I'd also like to be add two vectors together, as well as two normals, so I have blocks that look like this:

```
impl Add<Vector> for Vector {
  type Output = Vector;
  fn add(self, rhs: Vector) -> Vector {
    Vector { vals: [
      self.x() + rhs.x(), 
      self.y() + rhs.y(), 
      self.z() + rhs.z()] }
  }
}
```

And almost the exact same `impl` for `Normal`s. What I really want is to provide a default `Add impl` for every struct that implements `Components`, since typically, they all will add the same way (e.g. a third struct called `Point` will do the same thing). Is there a way of doing this besides writing out three identical implementations for `Point`, `Vector`, and `Normal`? Something that might look like this:

```
impl Add<Components> for Components {
  type Output = Components;
  fn add(self, rhs: Components) -> Components {
    Components::new(
      self.x() + rhs.x(), 
      self.y() + rhs.y(), 
      self.z() + rhs.z())
  }
}
```

Where "`Components`" would automatically get replaced by the appropriate type. I suppose I could do it in a macro, but that seems a little hacky to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Rust, it is possible to define generic `impl`s, but there are some important restrictions that result from the coherence rules. You'd like an `impl` that goes like this:

```
impl<T: Components> Add<T> for T {
  type Output = T;
  fn add(self, rhs: T) -> T {
    T::new(
      self.x() + rhs.x(), 
      self.y() + rhs.y(), 
      self.z() + rhs.z())
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not compile:

> error: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g. `MyStruct<T>`); only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter [[E0210](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0210)]

Why? Suppose your `Components` trait were public. Now, a type in another crate could implement the `Components` trait. That type might also try to implement the `Add` trait. Whose implementation of `Add` should win, your crate's or that other crate's? By Rust's current coherence rules, the other crate gets this privilege.

For now, the only option, besides repeating the `impl`s, is to use a macro. Rust's standard library uses macros in many places to avoid repeating `impl`s (especially for the primitive types), so you don't have to feel dirty! :P

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Are there any plans on providing support for something like this?

Comment: I don't know the exact plans, but to me, it seems like it would be possible to allow this if the trait is private (not exported from the crate) or if the `impl` could be marked as private (which is not possible right now).

Answer (score 4):

At present, macros are the only way to do this. Coherence rules prevent multiple implementations that could overlap, so you can’t use a generic solution.