# How can you implement a std Trait for every type that already implements other related std traits

Tags: rust, traits

So I have several structs I have implemented the Add and Neg traits on.
I now want to implement the Sub trait on them
What I want is to be able to write something along those lines

```
impl<T: Add + Neg> Sub for T{
type Output = self
   fn sub(self, rhs:Self) -> Self{
       self + (-rhs)
   }
}
```

but this gives me the error:
implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local
only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter

last time I encountered the problem I had copy paste the impl block for every relevant type. not that time consuming but ugly.
only found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430659/providing-blanket-trait-implementations-for-a-custom-trait?noredirect=1&lq=1) from 2015, apparently the only way to do this was with macros but in my case it would be worse. I'm wondering if there's another way to do that now

Comment: Rust's [orphan and coherence rules](https://github.com/Ixrec/rust-orphan-rules#what-are-the-orphan-rules) don't allow you to do this. Is this your real usecase? I feel like most types that implement `Add` and `Neg` would already implement `Sub` anyways.

Comment: How would using macros be worse? You could just write a macro so that you only need to do `impl_sub!(Typename)`

Comment: No, there is no way (but your link is to the home page). But why not using macros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

Rust uses the Orphan Rule to ensure the coherence of the trait implementations.

Coherence means that a certain type should only implement a trait for zero or one time (It is called 'overlapping' when some type implements a trait for more than once), which could be easily checked during a single compilation. But in fact, implementations could still overlap when the types, traits, and implementations are defined across crates.

The crate system is designed with an assertion of that it must be purely additional (which mean it cannot break any existing code) when any new crate is introduced to a compilation. In other words, it should be ensured that A crate, along with all of its dependencies, could compile with no problem, as long as each dependencies could compile alone with no problem. A very obvious example is that, when crate `a` and `b` are irrelative crates that both provide their implementation of a certain type for a certain trait, they could successfully compile alone, but if another trait `c` depends on both `a` and `b`, that implementation of such type for such trait, as crate `c` could see, is overlapping.

The Orphan Rule could be simply explained as that, as for a certain type and a certain trait, only the definer crate of the type, or the definer of the trait, could define implementation of the trait for the type. In other words, once both the type and the trait are defined, whether and how the type implements the trait is fully decided and can no longer be added or overlapped by the down-stream crates. Therefore, as for any crates that could see both the type and the trait, they must see the same zero or one implementation of a trait for a type.

Note that a generic parameter may also refer to a foreign type (a type that is not defined by the current crate), it is not possible to implement a foreign trait for a generic parameter